# Hibernate unable to insert

Tags: java, hibernate

Creating Session Factory here:

```
public class DBUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static{
        try{
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibtut")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "")
            .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5")
            .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "10")
            .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "1800")
            .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50")
            .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
            .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect")
            .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(MenuDHO.class);
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static void shutDown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Menudho.class is here:

```
package com.pra.shasoc.dho;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name="menu")
public class MenuDHO implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name="Name")
private String name;

@Column(name="Order")
private int order;
public MenuDHO() {
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getOrder() {
    return order;
}
public void setOrder(int order) {
    this.order = order;
}
}


public class MenuReader {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DBUtil dbUtil = new DBUtil();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = dbUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    MenuDHO menuDHO = new MenuDHO();
    menuDHO.setId(5);
    menuDHO.setName("New Menu");
    menuDHO.setOrder(15);
    session.save(menuDHO);
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

I get the following Exception:

PLEASE HELP

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Hibernate: insert into menu (Name, Order, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at com.pra.shasoc.helpers.MenuReader.main(MenuReader.java:18)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order, ID) values ('New Menu', 15, 5)' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2024)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1449)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order, ID) values ('New Menu', 15, 5)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1976)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use "Order" (the case doesn't matter in sql) as a column name because it is a reserved word (ORDER BY).